# dotnet new --install shows usage information

Tags: powershell, .net-core, command-line-interface, dotnet-cli

When I try to install a new template using the following:

`dotnet new --install . --name MyTemplate`
or
`dotnet new --install "Path" --name MyTemplate`

I get the usage information:

```
Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --dry-run           Displays a summary of what would happen if the given command line were run if it would result in a template creation.
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.
```

I have a `.template.config` directory with a `template.json` file within.

The contents of the `template.json` file are something like this:

```
{
    "author": "My Department",
    "classifications": [
        "Solution Template"
    ],
    "name": "My Template Name",
    "identity": "My Template Identity",
    "shortName": "mytemplate",
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#"
    },
    "sourceName": "Company.Product",
    "preferNameDirectory": "true"
}
```

I certainly wish it would tell me what I'm doing wrong.  This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: You don't need a `--name` parameter right? And the `.` should be the Nuget package name or path to local file.

Comment: You're right, I don't need a --name parameter, but I get the same result whether I include it or not.  I'm trying to install the template from the file system as opposed to a NuGet package, so NuGet is not applicable here.

Comment: @DavidG - Yes, it contains the `.template.config` folder.

Comment: I would love it if there were an error message, but there is none.

Comment: Error: Could not install "c:\".
Error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path

Comment: When I use the directory containing my template, I only see the usage information...  Weird.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your template then? It's not listed in the installed templates already?

Comment: Uhg...  Stackoverflow always makes me feel stupid.  It was actually installing the template, but also showing the usage information which is what was confusing me.  Submit that as an answer and I'll make it as the answer.

Comment: There is a bug logged as well, you could add that you were confused by seeing the help text which to be fair would make me think the same! https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1773

Comment: @MartinUllrich Good idea, done!

Comment: Have added an answer and will clean up the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the `dotnet new --install` command works is a bit confusing unfortunately. The installation can be successful but the output does not make it obvious. You will get the usage information and a list of installed templates that should include your new one.

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259025/dotnet-new-install-shows-usage-information#comment99135613_56259025), there is a [bug filed](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1773) that aims to tidy this up.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing similar results running `dotnet new -i IdentityServer4.Templates`, but the package wasn't being installed and no error or other info was being displayed.

Turns out nuget.org wasn't configured as a package source (new machine I guess? - thought that was configured by default when installing visual studio though).

Here's the nuget.org feed at the time of this writing:

> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

And here's info for configuring them in case it helps someone who hasn't done that:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources